# changing pointer members of a subroutine argument with intent(in)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran2003

I'm writing a sparse matrix library in Fortran for fun but came into a little snag. I have a subroutine for matrix multiplication with the interface

```
subroutine matvec(A,x,y)
    class(sparse_matrix), intent(in) :: A
    real(double_precision), intent(in) :: x(:)
    real(double_precision), intent(inout) :: y(:)
    {etc.}
```

This uses a sparse matrix type that I've defined myself, the implementation of which is unimportant. Now, I can make things nicer and have a lot less code if `A` contains an object called `iterator`:

```
type :: sparse_matrix
    type(matrix_iterator) :: iterator
    {etc.}
```

which stores a few variables that keep track of things during `matvec`. But, if I change the state of `iterator` and in turn the state of `A` during matrix multiplication, the compiler will throw a fit because `A` has intent(in) for that subroutine.

Suppose I change things around and instead define

```
type :: sparse_matrix
    type(matrix_iterator), pointer :: iterator
    {etc.}
```

It's no problem if I change the state of iterator during a procedure in which a matrix has intent(in), because the value of the pointer to iterator doesn't change; only the memory stored at that address is affected. This is confirmed by making a reduced test case, which compiles and runs just fine using GCC.

**Am I correct in thinking this is an appropriate fix**? Or should I change the subroutine so that A has intent(inout)? The fact that it compiled with GCC doesn't necessarily mean it's standard-compliant, nor does it mean it's good programming practice.

To make an analogy with C, suppose I had a function `foo(int* const p)`. If I wrote

```
*p = 42;
```

this would be ok, as the value of the pointer doesn't change, only the data stored at the address pointed to. On the other hand, I couldn't write

```
p = &my_var;
```

because it's a constant pointer.

Comment: If you need the iterator to vary in the subroutine, it probably would be a good idea to make it `intent(inout)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is OK. Actually this practice is well known and it is used, for example, when doing reference counting memory management, because the right hand side of defined assignment is an `intent(in)` expression, but you must be able to decrease the reference count in it.